# Store average data along with the table name into another table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, arduino, average

I want to store the average values from one table to another table.And also I need to store the table name in another column along with its average data using mysql.Here below is the table I need to have.

Need to add test table's average values into "avg table" along with the test **table name** as a **test id** for the second table
I dont know how to add tables in here.

[Test 1 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1bgm.png)

[AvgData table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0aOo.png)

Comment: At least consider that this *might* be a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to aggregate by date and then take the averages of the temperature and humidity columns:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE(Time) AS Date,
    AVG(Temperature) AS Avg_Temperature,
    AVG(Humidity) AS Avg_Humidity
FROM Test1
GROUP BY
    DATE(Time);
```

Comment: yes i also need to add it to another table along with the first table name